# Writing HTML links containing information about each file?

Tags: html

I am creating a website using HTML, CSS and Jquery and I need to add about 300 images to a gallery I created on the site. Is there any easy way to write the HTML necessary to link to these images? I need to include the location of each image as well as the file size, dimensions and file name which will go inside data-* attributes.

If there is a better way of doing all this I would be interested in hearing about that too.

I am using Aptana studio 3 if that helps.

Comment: This is a bit hacky, but you can use any spreadsheet application to concatenate strings - you just need all the image information in a spreadsheet, then you can just do one simple equation to generate the HTML which you then copy and paste into your editor

Comment: No server side code is being used?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Didn't think of that, know of any way to import image details into Excel? Couldn't see anything with a quick google.

Comment: Possibly this which extracts EXIF information to CSV: http://www.br-software.com/extracter.html . Never used it though.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not right now, the site works properly without any server side code but I would be open to including some, unfortunately I have no experience with that at all.

Comment: PHP and a tiny MYSQL database would handle it in seconds, and it's not that tricky

Answer (score 1):

For Linux and Mac you can do the following (on Windows you'll have to install Perl which is free from [activestate.com](http://activestate.com/%20%22ActiveState) and instead of *file* you would have to install *ImageMagick* and use the **identiy** command but you'll have to adjust the regex):

```
file * | perl -n -e '/([^:]+):\s+[A-Z]+ image data, (\d+) x (\d+)/ && print "<a href=\"$1\" data-width=\"$2\" data-height=\"$3\" data-size=\"" . (stat($1))[7] . "\">$1 is $2 by $3 pixels</a>\n"'
```

This will find every image file in a directory and output an HTML line. You can format as you like. If you need to go recursively down through multiple directories, replace *file* with

```
find . -type -f -exec file {} \; | perl -n -e etc...
```

Or something like that.

I do suggest that you don't do this, at all. Because anytime any of your files change or you add (or remove) any, you'll have to remake your page. Instead, get a file listing via AJAX and generate the HTML using Javascript. That way it will automatically reflect the actual contents of your image directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. About your suggestion, I'm trying to maintain functionality for users with Javascript disabled, so I guess I would have to forgo this if I were to use AJAX? Though it definitely seems like the better option.

Comment: What I wrote in my example does not rely on Javascript. It just spits out HTML which you can paste into your main HTML file. I can write an AJAX version, if you want to do that instead but, as you say, it wouldn't work for people who have Javascript disabled.

Comment: I may have to take that as a tradeoff, flexibility is more important. How would you do this in AJAX?